# Is it possible to execute a :normal command ignoring user-defined maps?

Tags: vimscript, key-bindings

Let us suppose that a user maps `-` to `<nop>`. How can I, as a script writer, execute a `:normal` command that correctly uses the default behaviour of `-`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to put `!` after `:normal` like this:

```
:normal! -
```

`!` will make it ignore mappings. From [`:help :normal`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/various.txt.html#:normal):

> If the [!] is given, mappings will not be used.
>   Without it, when this command is called from a
>   non-remappable mapping (:noremap), the argument can
>   be mapped anyway.

Comment: Is there a way to ignore a single mapping from normal mode, without needing to go into `:normal! ...`?

Comment: @EhteshChoudhury Nothing I'm aware of.  Searching also didn't find anything.  I think it's probably better to open a question.  It's likely that any answer will be too involved for the comments anyway.  Make sure to explain exactly what you want to do.  It will help the people answering the question.