# How to execute a command in normal mode ignoring any mappings made to it?

Tags: key-bindings, normal-mode

For example, if I have the mapping `nnoremap p ]p`
and want to put text only once with the unmapped `p` behaviour, is there a key I can press before `p` to bypass those mappings? Something like a shell `command` command.

I tried `<c-v>p` and `i<c-o>p` but that didn't do the trick.

Note that I'm trying to learn if there's a built-in feature that does that to various commands; I'm not looking for a solution that solves this case specifically, like `nnoremap <leader>p p`.

Also, there's  a [similar question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/8305/33012) out there, but that is not about executing the normal command from normal mode.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:normal! p`, the `:normal` command executes its argument as a sequence of Normal-mode commands, and the `!` modifier bypasses any mappings.

See [`:help :normal`](https://vimhelp.org/various.txt.html#%3Anormal) for more details.

Comment: This executes an ex command while in command-line mode, so it doesn't answer the question. Thanks for you time, though :)

Comment: Sure, I understand that, but `:` gets you there from Normal mode. Why necessarily a restriction of staying in Normal mode and not going through Command-line mode to accomplish this?

Comment: because it feels like it's a feature vim might just have and I just don't know about it. It's also more convenient to a workflow and, if normal mode has it, maybe it is also available in visual mode(where the `:normal! p` trick doesn't seem to work)

Comment: @anakimluke in visual mode, a mapping could use `<Cmd>normal! p` instead.